# qTip breaking Jquery date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, qtip2

If I remove qtip Js file from layouts. I am able to do date functionality. If qTip library added. both qTip and date picker not working.

```
//Loading Jquery UI library
//Loading qTip library

$("#BirthDate").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: '-110:-17',
    showOn: "button",  
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    beforeShow: function () {
        $('#ui-datepicker-div').css('z-index', 9999);
    },
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    maxDate: '-17Y'
}); 

$('.tip').qtip({
    style: {
        classes: 'myTipClass tipShadow qtip-rounded'
    }
});
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: nope.. no error showing

Comment: That makes the problem hard to diagnose. Do you need to use qtip when standard jQuery tooltips/dialog might suffice?